# using a managed server bean and POI to create a word doc

Tags: apache-poi, xpages

Has anyone got simple examples of creating and manipulating a word doc in a managed server bean?

I've managed to do this in a xAgent - but all POI documentation is JAVA based so I thought it would be easier to debug using a bean.

Just struggling to get started

Would like to email or download the file from a button on an xpage

Comment: This should get you started: https://quintessens.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/using-apache-poi-to-create-presentations-from-your-xpages-application/. You should also look at POI4XPages: https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten: Hm, all mentioned `apache poi` versions are outdated. Current version is `5.0.0`. And "POI Version 3.14 included" is not a good idea since that prevents one from using a more current version at all. You cannot have differnt `apache poi` versions in class path as this leads to errors.

Comment: @Per Henrik - seen both these - trying to use latest poi.
Just a Java beginner so struggling with concepts
Would I create a public class in my bean and the then be able to access it by .getDoc method?